# Regex - how to match subgroups

Tags: regex, expression, match

I've got an expression like this:

```
/* pierwszy */  using System;/* drugi */
```

and I want to match all comments in this line.

But this regex:

```
\/\*(.*)\*\/
```

is unfortunately not working, because it matches that:

```
pierwszy */  using System;/* drugi
```

So, as you can see, it matches the whole expression. Anybody knows how to write a regex to match subgroups, not the whole expression?

Comment: Use `\/\*(.*?)\*\/` if you have short one-line only comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\/\*([\w|\s]*)\*\/
```

It will match any word or space character between `/*` and `*/`

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
\/\*\s*([^\s]+)\s*\*\/
```

Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/2efy8S/1) for a working demo.